# Tableau combining rows with the same info

Tags: data-visualization, tableau-api

I have a dashboard in Tableau which shows different payments received - the amount, the date the payment was received, and a calculated field which shows the number days since the payment was received.

However, a lot of payments are the same, with the same amount, and received on the same day; so Tableau collapses these together, and adds the total days since the payments were received together in the final column, i.e. five lots of £5.50, each received on 1st January shows as below (as of 01/02/2018)

```
Column 1   Column 2     Column 3
£5.50     01/01/2018      155
```

But I need separate rows for each. Does anyone know how to stop tableau doing this, or of a workaround? 
Many thanks.

Comment: do you need aggregated data (ie: number of days - column 3) or just a list of your payments (in your case 5 different rows with the same data for column 1-2-3)?

Comment: Hi, five different rows for the same data is needed. Thanks.

Comment: did the answer solved your problem? if so, please accept it, in order to make the thread complete

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly on one of the dashboards, but not all; but i should be able to figure the why. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using RANK_UNIQUE function.

First of all, in the Analysis Menu, uncheck Aggregate Measures.

Then, starting from this data:

[image]

You can get this result:
[image]

Additionally, you may want to hide Rank from rows just not-showing header.

Is this something close to what you're looking for?

**EDIT/UPDATE**

In order to get all values and not just for the top rows, just move the Rank at the very beginning of the shelf:

[image]